# How to create a nested msxml6.msi package

Tags: visual-studio-2005, setup-project, orca

How to add msxml6.msi as nested package into my vs 2005 setup (Based.msi) using Orca? I already used this instructions http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306439 , but msxml6.msi installation never started.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin, I used prerequisites option, but I had to add also msxml32/64 packages into c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\ for 2005 under win 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested installations are deprecated. You should either use a prerequisite, or a custom action.

Here is a small prerequisite tutorial for Visual Studio 2005: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Prerequisites_in_Setup.aspx

You can try using the [bootstrapper manifest generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) to configure your prerequisite.

If you want to use a custom action, you can either try launching msiexec.exe with the appropriate command line or write custom code which launches the MSI.

This custom action should be executed after **InstallFinalize** in *InstallExecuteSequence* table. It should also use the [msidbCustomActionTypeAsync and msidbCustomActionTypeContinue flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368071%28VS.85%29.aspx).